# I have a problem with django-taggit persian[farsi-fa]

Tags: django, django-taggit, farsi

I have a problem when I put persian tags in the Django admin panel I get this error in template:

```
Reverse for 'post_tag' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tags/(?P<tag_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']
```

**Note:** when I put English and other languages tag I don't get this error and it works True.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import model
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ArticleTagList(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'blog/list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('tag_slug'))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.url import path
from .views import ArticleTagList

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("tags/<slug:tag_slug>/", ArticleTagList.as_view(), name='post_tag'),
    ...
]
```

**blog/list.html**

```
 ...
 
 {% for tag in article.tags.all %}
     <a href="{% url 'blog:post_tag' tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
 {% endfor %}

 ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNLne.png)

I change django-taggit version to last version bun not working. I'm now using 3.1.0 version.
What can I do? Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into similar error while trying to work with cyrillic tags. The problem turned out to be not in django-taggit itself, but in the path converter. Just like you, I used slug in my urlpatterns, and it only worked with latin letters, giving me 'Reverse not found' error whenever I switched to cyrillic.

The problem here is, slug path converter only understands ASCII symbols, which only contains latin letters. I changed it to str path converter, `'tags/<str:tag_slug>'`, and it worked with cyrillic tags just fine, so maybe it'll work for you as well.